# Formatting email sent by HTML, to include images and table

Tags: html, email

So I run a local football website and sometimes teams need to submit forms to the league. The form contains some basic text fields and then it sends an email to various recipients. This all works fine, the problem is the format of these emails is rubbish, and I'm trying to enhance the style of these emails, by adding the league logo and then structuring the data in a table and potentially bolding headers etc. Nothing complex but not sure how to go about this and the searches I've found and attempts tried just end up in errors.
So, in summary, I want to add:

1. Logo to the top of the body (say 50x50 size)
2. Put about 5/6 items of data into a 2 column table (light grey border maybe), with column 1 with bold headers
   Any help appreciated.
   Thanks

This is the current code:

```
    //Create the email and send the message
    $to = $sendto; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com -     
    This is where the form will send a message to.
    $email_subject = "EMERGENCY Player Registration Request Form: Team Submitted $team1";
    $email_body = "Hello Div Sec for $agegroup, you have received the following EMERGENCY Player   
    Registration request.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nSent From: $sentfrom\n\nRole: $role\n\nTeam   
    Submitted: $team1\n\nPlayer Name(s): $reason";
    $headers = "From: player_reg@league.co.uk\n"; // This is the email address the generated message  
    will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
    $headers .= "CC: $sentfromemail,publicity@league.co.uk";
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    echo "<br><br><center><h6>Thank you for your request. This has been sent to your Divisional    
    Secretary and to the email you provided. <br>Please use the menu items to navigate to your next  
    destination";
    return true;
```

So what I have tried to do is in the "$email_body =" section, is add the usual img src type code as I have elsewhere but when I do this and test it, is where I get the errors. Haven't got the table part yet as if I can't add a simple image in yet then no idea how I'm supposed to get a table to work!So I guess I want the below to look like this:

```
    $email_body = "***IMAGE HERE*** Hello Div Sec for $agegroup, you have received the following      
    EMERGENCY Player Registration request.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\n ***COL 1 ROW 1 STRONG  
    HERE *** Sent From: ***COL 2 ROW 1 HERE ***$sentfrom\n\nRole: $role\n\nTeam Submitted:   
    $team1\n\nPlayer Name(s): $reason";

Any advice please?
```